# Parity Kovan shows TX id but 0 balance in Smart Contract

Tags: parity, metamask, contract-debugging, kovan

I make this tx: 0x6d5c2CC2e1454B493E4090fA3995226245c8b744
which shows raw tx:

```
{
  "blockHash": "0xc101da80e396878a572dc3024c5423479e5e45a9c622af5621ad521fe86cd8af",
  "blockNumber": "6007464",
  "chainId": "0x2a",
  "condition": null,
  "creates": "",
  "from": "0x33dbe8478805cf734184aeD8737607656252D804",
  "gas": "2649987",
  "gasPrice": "1000000000",
  "hash": "0xf85549de4c283f2f5b216c692beaab7faf09eb3386d98cad9cbada99b232802a",
  "input": "0x3eb76b9c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  "nonce": "66",
  "publicKey": "0x014b1e4d717170123a4cdcac04cb3bb93783cc8dc207bb63f00e3c78b0cf83a61363010f1c720f6e26d1b71ebd5192e739539531f7ced81066ed71e2dbe1f780",
  "r": "0xd88c98848910ac44da9abccc38eadf38b47d4b1a190388b2b8d523276e625f7",
  "raw": "0xf88f42843b9aca0083286f83946d5c2cc2e1454b493e4090fa3995226245c8b74487038d7ea4c68000a43eb76b9c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000177a00d88c98848910ac44da9abccc38eadf38b47d4b1a190388b2b8d523276e625f7a072dfc82735aeb8703d6fdb872f519418e1f3258380e5417ca52aab8cb6f48327",
  "s": "0x72dfc82735aeb8703d6fdb872f519418e1f3258380e5417ca52aab8cb6f48327",
  "standardV": "0x0",
  "to": "0x6d5c2CC2e1454B493E4090fA3995226245c8b744",
  "transactionIndex": "0",
  "v": "0x77",
  "value": "1000000000000000"
}
```

block #6,007,464 (0xc1..af)

so I expect smart contract address

`"0x6d5c2CC2e1454B493E4090fA3995226245c8b744"` to have 0.001

but it does not, it has 0.000 balance. I've tried sending a tx a few times and each time it completes with a transaction ID but does not show.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: I found a warning, error in contract execution. I'm surprised the tx still goes through in Metamask without an error? Is there a better way to debug this besides looking through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your main fallback function is not payable , I think:

`function () payable {
main.handlePayment.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
}`

Best way to debug this is to use `truffle debug` see this http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/debugging or `remix debug` https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_mist.html